# ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: foreign-keys, mysql

I have the following database and when I try to run the query that has been shown below I get the error that says `Cannot add or update a child row`. I do not understand why am I getting this error.

The `object_id` that I am entering (327) exists in the database. I have tried this with other `object_id`s as well and the same error comes up. What is happening here?

```
    like_objects
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| object_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

objects
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| object_name  | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| object_desc  | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| likes        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here's the query and the error it produces:

```
insert into  like_objects (object_id,user_id) values (327,1)

ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`test_db`.`like_objects`, CONSTRAINT `object_id_refs_id_57f96810` FOREIGN KEY (`object_id`) 
REFERENCES `objects` (`id`))
```

This is very strange because I have used a similar `like` logic for another table and it is working absolutely fine.

**Important** I have obtained `objects` table from a `mysqldump`. Initially the `objects` table was created form PhpMyAdmin and the like_objects table has been created by the `django models`

Comment: Please add the results from the sanity check (i.e. `select * from objects where id = 327`) to the post.

Comment: Also, it might help to add the `create table` statements for both tables.

Comment: @MattFenwick: As the object_desc is a longtext the result of this query is very long. I Can't copy the whole thing but as expected I am getting the correct tuple. The `id` does exist in the table.

Comment: Also as I said I obtained this table from mysqldump and the original table was created a long time back and I don't exactly remember the `create table` but back then I did it using `phpmyadmin`

Comment: `show create table like_objects;`

Comment: Since `id` is the PK of `objects`, then the sanity check query would return at most 1 row.

Comment: The sanity check query returned 1 row only as expected and as I have written in my answer I have figured out the problem. There was nothing wrong with the table schema or the foreign key being not present, it was incompatibility with the storage engine. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out what the problem was. As I have posted in my question that the `objects` table was created using `phpmyadmin` and then dumped into my database which is part of a `django project`.

So the storage engine of the initially created table was `MyISAM`, but the tables created by django were having storage engine `innodb`. So as result whenever I tried to insert an object in the `like_objects` table which referenced the `objects` table there was this incompatibility of the the storage types.

This [link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-table-storage-engine/) helped me to find out what was the storage engine for my table and then I changed the MyISAM engine to innodb using the belwo given command and it is working fine.

```
ALTER TABLE products ENGINE = innodb
```